# Is it possible to import a newsgroup into a TFS discussion?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

We're considering switching over to use TFS and the TFS Portal which is based on SharePoint. We've got existing information in various systems and it would be very advantageous if we could consolidate this information into the TFS Portal.

I'm wondering are there any tools/methods for importing data into TFS. Things I'm interested in importing are:

- Newsgroups - that could be put into TFS discussions.
- Fogbugz - that could be put into TFS work-items. (sorry Joel)
- A TWiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it is very difficult to import the history from one TFS repository into another, I suspect the import of other types of data will be just as hard.

On the otherhand, there is a [decent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx), so it shouldn't be hard to write something yourself.

Check out [Rob Caron's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/robcaron/) and the [TFS API Examples](http://www.tfsexamples.com/default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) site.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small clarification. There are no TFS discussion groups. TFS uses SharePoint WSS as a collaboration tool. So, you might find better results if you search for any tools that import things to WSS Discussions. You can also find third party discussion web parts which you can install on the WSS site.